# How to create parameterized test run in Flutter test group from dynamically returned data

Tags: dart, flutter-test

I want to create parameterized tests with Flutter. I have forEach loop that I want to use to generate parameterized tests based on what application responds to me. Any ideas how to do it? I thought of:

```
    group('Group for tests', () {
      test("Get necessary list from app_handler", () {
        expect(app_handler.async_function1(driver).then((value) => myListOfItems), completes;
        expect(myListOfItems, isNotEmpty);
      });

      myListOfItems.forEach((myItem) {
        test("Test for $myItem", () {
          expect(app_handler.async_function2(driver, myItem), completes);
        });
      });
```

but this does not work. `myListOfItems` fails empty check in the first test and it should be a populated list.
So I somehow need to prepare test cases dynamically based on what app responds to me during test.

Comment: You need to initialize `myListOfItems` *outside* of a callback to `package:test`.

Comment: @jamesdlin That was done initially, it is initialized outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @Alessio discussion and @jamesdlin comment I ended up with solution that involves creating a file with data after one test and then using this file during another test.

```
     group('Smoke test', () {
       test("Get my vals", () async {
         final myVals= await app_handler.getMyVals(driver);
         expect(myVals, isNotEmpty);
         final file = File('myVals.json');
         file.writeAsString(jsonEncode({'myVals':myVals}));
       });
     }, tags: "Test_1");

    group('Main test', () {
      final file = File('myVals.json');
      final myVals = (json.decode(file.readAsStringSync())['exceptions'] as List).cast<String>();
      myVals.forEach((myVal) {
      test("Test $myVal", () {
        expect(app_handler.async_func(driver, myVal), completes);
      });
    }, tags: "Test_2"););
```

So test executor will first call test with first tag then with second and during second testrun tests will be generated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the test() method async, and then await for your async method to complete. (edited)

Comment: No I cannot. I mentioned that this is the point that I need this test to be non async

Comment: @ArturKorobeynyk why such requirement? Marking the test method async, but internally waiting for something, doesn't really make the test async.

Comment: Because it calls methods used in other parts of software that return Future object. Other tests will depend on results of this test so I don't want to start other tests in co-routine before this one is finished. I am kind of implementing parametrised approach for tests

Comment: Not related, but this part "Following tests will depend on results of this test" sounds very bad to me. That given, I don't see or know much more alternatives than this. You can't flat async but propagating the async annotation all the levels upwards and dealing with it.

Comment: Why in this case .then() and .whenComplete() methods exist?

Comment: The .then() doesn't flatten your execution, that part - as you know - gets executed later on. If you try that in a test, the test will fail, because the test will continue and compare before the .then() is actually executed. Also, better to try to understand what I write as I'm here trying to help you out, instead of giving me negative points which makes me stop helping you out.

Comment: @ArturKorobeynyk You're asking the wrong question.  This has nothing to do with `async` callbacks to `test()`.  Tests do not run concurrently, even if they have `async` callbacks.  You also will find that even if you have tests that do *not* have `async` callbacks, code *outside* of tests will execute before the `test` callbacks fire.